# Command to find which version of armadillo is installed?

Tags: armadillo

I tried `armadillo -v` and `ldconfig -p | grep arma*` , but neither one helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
arma::arma_version ver;
std::cout << "ARMA version: "<< ver.as_string() << std::endl;
```

Comment: The above works. Just to simplify it further, you can use the following [code](https://gist.github.com/sidak/72e73bd8576124c2aeb6df1b3fb6d31d) to test it.